# Slow Macbook Pro - Very low %Idle number

Tags: macbook-pro

My Macbook Pro started acting very strange from one day to another. I started researching a bit and found someone who suggested that i might have high processor utilization. I checked my Activity Monitor and saw that under the tab "CPU" the "%Idle" numbers were very low but i couldn't see which app was causing it. What can i do about this? I do not know a lot about computers so any kind of help is appreciated!  [image: activity monitor]

Comment: Per the breakdown, the CPU is being utilised by the system. In the toolbar, change My Processes to All Processes to show all processes, even those owned by the system.

Comment: I just did that and i see that kernel task is at the top of the list. And I just found out that it is normal for it to use most RAM. But i still can't figure out why my computers seems to be working so hard but still being so slow.

Answer (score 2):

Your system processes are 81.46%. In the overview, in the top bar of the window, you selected "My Processes". If you change that to "All" you'll see which process is taking up all your CPU power.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just changed to "All Processes" and at the top of the list is something called Kernel-task. I have no idea what that is and if/how i close it.

Comment: @Matilda Kernel is a helper so it does work on behalf of others. It could be a hardware malfunction where the CPU is overheating and not scheduling any work (and accounting for things in the kernel) or more likely just that there is disk activity or other system overhead. If you restart your Mac - you can tell if this is an ongoing problem or due to a runaway process or program.